# Change HTML drag and drop cursor

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

is there any way to remove or change this cursor while using html drag and drop function. I want to remove that rect below arrow while you dragging.

I tried to remove the cursor with css and similar things but its not use.
Is this even possible to make?

[image]